# With iOS13, is it allowed to report CXCallUpdate or CXEndCallAction when a VoIP Push is received?

Tags: swift, push, voip, ios13, callkit

I wonder if is it allowed to report `CXCallUpdate` or `CXEndCallAction` inside the method below when a VoIP Push is received.

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
  // report new incoming call
}
```

Official documentation just mentions reporting newNewIncomingCall [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry) in that block. HEre is relevant part of the documentation.

> When linking against the iOS 13 SDK or later, your implementation of
>   this method must report notifications of type voIP to the CallKit
>   framework by calling the
>   reportNewIncomingCall(with:update:completion:) method of your app's
>   CXProvider object.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the relevant document which describes how a VoIP push should be handled is just updated on the official Apple documentation website.

It says don't send any other VoIP push to the application other than an incoming call which means we can not report CXCallUpdate or CXEndCallAction once a VoIP push is received.

The relevant part of the document can be seen below

After sending the initial push notification, don’t send additional push notifications to cancel the call or communicate new details to your app. Instead, communicate with the app directly over the network connection you established between it and your server. Using an existing network connection is generally faster than sending a push notification, and if network conditions are poor, APNs may be unable to deliver push notifications to the device anyway.

Here is also official documentation which is just updated

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, on iOS 13 and later, you must report a call to CallKit when you receive a VoIP push. But, as soon as you have reported the call and as far as the call remains active, you can receive as many VoIP push as you want and do anything you want inside `pushRegistry(:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:type:)`.

Comment: So please correct me if I am wrong, you mean if I already report incoming call (that comes via VoIP push) to CallKit and if it remains active, I can still receive other VoIP pushes which is relevant to that call (such as callUpdate, callEnd) and I don't have to report that notifications to the CallKit, right @Marco ?

Comment: Exactly. You don't have to call the `reportNewIncomingCall(with:update:completion:)` method if you have already an active call.

Comment: I dont mean rereport incomingCall, I mean for example reporting CXCallEndAction.

Comment: I mean: when you don't have an active call you must call `reportNewIncomingCall(with:update:completion:)`, but when you have an active call you can do whatever you want when you receive a push.

Comment: But when we don't report other VoIP push to the CallKit after reporting incomingCall, we have encountered that iOS blocks our application to receive VoIP push but I'm not sure this is official behavior or not.